# Problems getting the Umbraco source code project to load in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: umbraco

I downloaded the source code of Umbraco CMS from codeplex. However I could not find the database script for this.

When I open the solution file it says that:

> Umbraco.Cms.Web.UI can not be loaded
>   as this is not a supported project
>   type.

I am running on windows 7 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2010.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you install all the prerequisites? (E.g. ASP.NET MVC?)

Comment: What version of the source? 4.7 or the pre-release v5?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have downloaded the Umbraco 5 source code, is this the one that you were after or are you after the 4.x source code?

I've written a few articles to get you started with downloading the Umbraco 5 source:

- http://www.aaron-powell.com/mercurial-101-for-umbraco-developers
- http://www.aaron-powell.com/umbraco-and-mercurial-how-to-contribute

If you are after the Umbraco 5 source code you'll need to ensure you meet the prerequisites, and for that info check out the Jupiter wiki:

- http://jupiter.umbraco.org/Getting-started-in-the-Jupiter-Codebase.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog article - it got me up and running w/out a problem with Win7 VS2010 on the 4.7 version of the code...have not tried V5 yet.

http://www.aaron-powell.com/how-i-developer-umbraco